# Does the logarithm of the Zeta Function approach minus infinity anyhow?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

The logarithm of zeta function $$\log \zeta (s)=\sum \sum \frac{1}{m} p^{-ms} $$
where the outer sum is over primes and the inner one is from 1 to infinity.
And expressing $$p^{-ms}$$ in term of real and imaginary parts of s yields, $$\sum \sum \frac{1}{m} p^{-ms} = \sum \sum \frac{1}{m} p^{-Bm}[cos(-\gamma In p)+isin(-\gamma  In p)]^m$$
In the critical zone where $$0<\operatorname{Re}(s)<1$$, $$\zeta(s)$$  is zero, when its logarithm approaches –$\infty$. But I see the sum above which represents the logarithm of the function can not be even negative. So my question, does that equation for the logarithm of the zeta function hold in the critical zone? If so, how the function can be then zero if the logarithm does not approach minus infinity?

Comment: The series representation $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}$$ together with the Euler product $$\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}$$ are converging only for $\text{Re}(s)>1$, hence you cannot directly say something about the behaviour of the $\zeta$ function in the critical strip through the above formulas. You need an analytic continuation, for instance the one provided by $$\eta(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s} = (1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s).$$

Comment: and of course the series $Re(\log \zeta(s)) = \sum_{p} \sum_{m \ge 1} \frac{p^{- Re(s)\,m}}{m} \cos(Im(s) \ln p^m), Re(s) > 1$ can be negative

Comment: You've an explanation such convergence from the official channel in YouTube of **Bonfert-Taylor**, *The Riemann Zeta Function and the Riemann Hypotheis*. Also a collection of videos by **MrYouMath** (he is an user of this site that has a channel in which explains the Riemann Zeta function); also you can see the schema in minute 12:18 from **singingbanana**, *The Riemann Hypothesis*. Thus from the answer and comments you see that if you want do calculations you need the right expression (see the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25)), sections 25.2 and 25.5.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the equation for the logarithmic zeta function hold in the critical strip?

No. In fact, the standard equation for the zeta function
$$ \zeta(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^s} $$
also does not hold in the critical strip, but only for $\text{Re}(s) > 1$. It is the same for the logarithmic zeta function.

In order to obtain information in the critical strip, you need some sort of meromorphic continuation.